# В сводной таблице googlesheets не считаются суммы по одному из столбцов (в строке формул такой формат - 12 290,00). В чем может быть причина?

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Единственное отличие данных в этом столбце - в строке формул. Число указано с пробелом между разрядами. При этом если складывать значения из ячеек в отдельной формуле - результат вычислений есть. В таблицу все значения попадают с помощью формулы importrange.[image: Вопрос по сумме в сводной таблице]

Answer (score 0):

В столбце `G` - текст. Нужно преобразовать в число - удалить пробелы.

Выделить диапазон, инструмент `Найти/Заменить` (*Ctrl+H*), найти пробел, ни на что не менять, `Заменить все`

Comment: Нет, не вариант. В поиске пробелов не находит, т.к. это данные из importrange.

Comment: Пока решил так - добавил столбец, в котором прописал =value(ячейки  G) и использовал его для создания сводной таблицы.